# Vimium-like navigation in Windows and all other applications

Tags: windows, user-interface, forms, mode

I used `Vimium` recently and was fascinated about its `'link hunt mode'` feature. I wonder if there exists any tool like it in Windows such that pressing <kbd>F</kbd> would auto-assign a key combination for all UI components (`checkbox`, `textbox`, `dropdown list`, etc.) on a `Windows form` and then pressing that key combination would focus the corresponding `UI element`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The LabelControl AutoHotkey script can overlay buttons, controls, and other interface elements with a number. You can access the interface controls at any time by inputting the number that belongs to one of them.

E.g. here is a GIF of the LabelControl AutoHotkey script with its numbers:

[image]

(LabelControl AutoHotkey script: http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/index.html#LabelControl).

I haven’t tried it though.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using [Hunt and Peck](https://github.com/zsims/hunt-and-peck).[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Fluent Search](https://www.fluentsearch.net/) has a Screen Search feature that works with any application. You can just set a key-binding to invoke it and use it.

[https://www.fluentsearch.net/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhLsZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Press **Alt** once in newer MS Office products (I guess >=2010) to get a 'link hunt mode'-style key shortcuts.

Comment: Yes. Windows Ribbon framework is quite good.But what about other apps which don't have ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

Another cool software is [KeyMouse](https://github.com/iscooool/KeyMouse). It's newer and more actively developedthan the Hunt and Peck.